# Swift - Trouble turning function into generic

Tags: ios, swift

I would like a generic function that returns the first subview of a given generic class.  At this point I do not think it is possible but I wanted to make sure.  Below is the function I would like to make generic and be able to substitute any item that is a child of UIView and responds to #subviews.

This works for ScrollViews

```
// Returns first UIScrollView in subviews of view
func searchFor(view: UIView) -> UIScrollView? {
    for v in view.subviews{
        let y = v as UIView
        if v is UIScrollView {
            return (v as UIScrollView)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I was hoping that if I passed an instance of the object type I was searching for I could derive the class type and use that in the:

```
if v is T
```

This compiles and runs but does find the view.

```
func searchFor<T>(view: UIView, t: T) -> T? {
    for v in view.subviews {
        println(v.self)
        println("Looking in view")
        if v is T {
            println("Found in searchFor<T>")
            return (v as T)
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

T is a metaType and I can't get it to reveal a class.  I guess I could extend the classes I wanted to search and add a description and do a switch statement on the string but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
extension Array {
    func firstOfType<X: AnyObject>(c: X.Type) -> X? {
        for x in self {
            if x is X { return (x as X) }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

var v = UIView()
v.addSubview(UIView())
v.addSubview(UIScrollView())
v.addSubview(UIButton())
v.addSubview(UIControl())

v.subviews.firstOfType(UIControl) // returns the UIButton
```

Or an alternative:

```
extension Array {
    func firstWhere(returnElement: T -> Bool) -> T? {
        var g = lazy(self).filter(returnElement).generate()
        return g.next()
    }
}

v.subviews.firstWhere { $0 is UIControl } // returns the UIButton
```

Comment: `if x is X { return x }`

Comment: Still need a cast but marginally cleaner. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Excellent!  Does exactly what I was looking for.